# symfony postgres doctrine dynamic relations. Как реализовать с сохранением в базе?

Tags: postgresql, symfony

В общем есть у меня обект вот в таком виде

```
{
    "delivery":{
    "street":"street name",
    "deliveryDetails": {
    } 
    }
}
```

deliveryDetails - один из трех объектов

```
office: {
    "roomSpaceVolume":float
}

machine: {
    "serialNumber":int
}
human: {
    "name":string
}
```

Как это сохранить в базе? с сохранением связей между зависимостями объектов (doctrine relations).
заблаговременно естественно неизвестно какой тип доставки будет. Хранить разные типы нужно в отдельных таблицах. У меня Postgres+Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Принцип: общая часть частично разных сущностей хранится в одной общей таблице, различия - в разных, которые имеют реляции с общей. В объектной области все выглядит прозрачно. Однако, 1. нужно иметь поле дискриминанта, на основе которого определяется соединение таблиц (например тип) 2. Каждый тип желательно иметь отдельным классом, наследуемым от одного общего

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло! Не самая лучшая реализация из всего что я видел, но все же работоспособная.